# Airflow on_failure_callback receive a context argument, but where can I find what the context contains?

Tags: airflow

Where can I find what the context dict contains?
I couldn't find anything about the keys it contains in the documentation or after some searches in Google.

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f0cf15cfe3a2f16741063d0368216b7067f38245/airflow/utils/context.pyi#L51 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The context is coming from the following [code line](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/9b05f027c3411ff5a5fec71ccf6826207ff9016d/airflow/models/dag.py#L1142).
It will have templated values of the following dict (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f0cf15cfe3a2f16741063d0368216b7067f38245/airflow/utils/context.pyi#L51-L92)):

```
class Context(TypedDict, total=False):
    conf: AirflowConfigParser
    conn: Any
    dag: DAG
    dag_run: DagRun
    data_interval_end: DateTime
    data_interval_start: DateTime
    ds: str
    ds_nodash: str
    execution_date: DateTime
    exception: Union[Exception, str, None]
    inlets: list
    logical_date: DateTime
    macros: Any
    next_ds: Optional[str]
    next_ds_nodash: Optional[str]
    next_execution_date: Optional[DateTime]
    outlets: list
    params: ParamsDict
    prev_data_interval_start_success: Optional[DateTime]
    prev_data_interval_end_success: Optional[DateTime]
    prev_ds: Optional[str]
    prev_ds_nodash: Optional[str]
    prev_execution_date: Optional[DateTime]
    prev_execution_date_success: Optional[DateTime]
    prev_start_date_success: Optional[DateTime]
    run_id: str
    task: BaseOperator
    task_instance: TaskInstance
    task_instance_key_str: str
    test_mode: bool
    templates_dict: Optional[Mapping[str, Any]]
    ti: TaskInstance
    tomorrow_ds: str
    tomorrow_ds_nodash: str
    ts: str
    ts_nodash: str
    ts_nodash_with_tz: str
    var: _VariableAccessors
    yesterday_ds: str
    yesterday_ds_nodash: str
```